# Market basket analysis with duplicated items in R using arules

Tags: r, apriori, arules

I am currently using the arules package to perform a market basket analysis. My data that I read in looks like this (but with many more rows):

```
>data
  transaction_id  item
1              1  beer
2              1  beer
3              1  soda
4              2  beer
5              3  beer
6              3  fries
7              3  candy
8              4  soda
9              4  fries
```

I then transform it using dcast and remove the transaction id column:

```
> Trans_Table <- dcast(data, transaction_id ~ item)
> Trans_Table$transaction_id <- NULL
```

and it looks like this:

```
  beer candy fries soda
1    2     0     0    1
2    1     0     0    0
3    1     1     1    0
4    0     0     1    1
```

but then when I make it into the "transactions" class so I can use the apriori function, it converts the 2 under beer to a 1

```
> Transactions <-  as(as.matrix(Trans_Table), "transactions")
Warning message:
In asMethod(object) :
  matrix contains values other than 0 and 1! Setting all entries != 0 to 1.
```

Is there any way to perform the market basket analysis and maintain that 2? In other words, I would like to see rules for {beer} => {beer}, {beer, beer} => {soda}, and {beer, soda} => {beer} but it is currently only counting beer once per each transaction even if it was purchased twice.

Can anyone help out with this?

Answer (score 4):

Market basket analysis is look at distinct items purchased together, and not frequency of a given item. But, if you really want to treat same item as if it were distinct, you can perhaps use the following approach to generate new item names.

Using library `dplyr`, you can mutate the item name to be appended by the an id of times it occurs, and use that in your arules processing:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
        group_by(transaction_id, item) %>%
        mutate(newitem = paste(item, row_number(), sep = ''))
as.matrix(table(df$transaction_id, df$newitem))
```

Output is:

```
    beer1 beer2 candy1 fries1 soda1
  1     1     1      0      0     1
  2     1     0      0      0     0
  3     1     0      1      1     0
  4     0     0      0      1     1
```

There are a couple of ways to tweak the output to fit the specific format style too.